# Last record from for loop is duplicated at each Cell forRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Small but probably stupid mistake here. I'm reading from a file from the documents Directory. I filter results based on the Value for a specific key. And anything with a specific string within that certain value I present into a UITableView. The number of rows is correctly populated, however the cell.textLabel.text isn't showing the correct names at each cell rowForAtIndexPath. My question is, am I iterating through my loop correctly? Am I setting the textLabel incorrectly due to the indexPath? I've attached a screenshot of the output and a NSLog statement showing the supposed indexPath of that specific object. Here is a snippet of code showing the willDisplayCell forRowAtIndexPath.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.row%2 == 0) {
    UIColor *altCellColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.7 alpha:0.2];
    cell.backgroundColor = altCellColor;
    }

for (int objectToDisplay = 0; objectToDisplay<[tableDataSourceArray count]; objectToDisplay++) {
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)objectToDisplay);
    NSString *objectTitle = [[tableDataSourceArray objectAtIndex:objectToDisplay] valueForKey:@"ConnectabilityObjectTitle"];
    NSString *pingResult = [[tableDataSourceArray objectAtIndex:objectToDisplay] valueForKey:@"ConnectivityPingTestResultValue"];
    NSString *portConnectResult = [[tableDataSourceArray objectAtIndex:objectToDisplay] valueForKey:@"ConnectivityPortConnectResultValue"];

    if ([pingResult containsString:@"Successful"]) {
        if ([portConnectResult isEqualToString:@"Successful"]) {
        } else {
            cell.textLabel.text = objectTitle;

            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Failed to connect to port for this server/service";
            NSLog(@"%@ at row %lu", objectTitle, (unsigned long)objectToDisplay);
        }
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = objectTitle;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Failed to ping this server/service";
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the NSLogStatement from the console.

```
2016-08-23 11:04:11.509 FlightPath[1346:551416] 0
2016-08-23 11:04:11.510 FlightPath[1346:551416] 1
2016-08-23 11:04:11.510 FlightPath[1346:551416] 2
2016-08-23 11:04:11.510 FlightPath[1346:551416] 3
2016-08-23 11:04:11.510 FlightPath[1346:551416] 4
2016-08-23 11:04:11.511 FlightPath[1346:551416] 5
2016-08-23 11:04:11.513 FlightPath[1346:551416] Store Drive at row 5
2016-08-23 11:04:11.513 FlightPath[1346:551416] 6
2016-08-23 11:04:11.514 FlightPath[1346:551416] 7
2016-08-23 11:04:11.514 FlightPath[1346:551416] 8
2016-08-23 11:04:11.514 FlightPath[1346:551416] 9
2016-08-23 11:04:11.515 FlightPath[1346:551416] 10
2016-08-23 11:04:11.515 FlightPath[1346:551416] 11
2016-08-23 11:04:11.515 FlightPath[1346:551416] 12
2016-08-23 11:04:11.517 FlightPath[1346:551416] 13
2016-08-23 11:04:11.517 FlightPath[1346:551416] 14
2016-08-23 11:04:11.517 FlightPath[1346:551416] 15
2016-08-23 11:04:11.518 FlightPath[1346:551416] 16
2016-08-23 11:04:11.518 FlightPath[1346:551416] 17
2016-08-23 11:04:11.518 FlightPath[1346:551416] 18
2016-08-23 11:04:11.518 FlightPath[1346:551416] 19
2016-08-23 11:04:11.519 FlightPath[1346:551416] 20
2016-08-23 11:04:11.519 FlightPath[1346:551416] 21
2016-08-23 11:04:11.519 FlightPath[1346:551416] 22
2016-08-23 11:04:11.522 FlightPath[1346:551416] 23
2016-08-23 11:04:11.522 FlightPath[1346:551416] 24
2016-08-23 11:04:11.522 FlightPath[1346:551416] StorewebP at row 24
2016-08-23 11:04:11.523 FlightPath[1346:551416] 25
2016-08-23 11:04:11.523 FlightPath[1346:551416] 26
2016-08-23 11:04:11.523 FlightPath[1346:551416] FIM DataCenter VIP at row 26
2016-08-23 11:04:11.524 FlightPath[1346:551416] 27
```

And here is a screenshot. 
[image: TableViewDuplicateOfLastRecordIssue]

Comment: Why do you have the for-loop?  Wouldn't you just use `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row` instead of `objectAtIndex:objectToDisplay`?

Comment: That for loop is essentially looping through an array that derive's from a file in the DocumentsDirectory. 

Since I'm iterating through this array, do you think the for loop is completely necessary. Please note that I'm looping through each record, and checking against values in order to display the cell with it's corresponding information.

Comment: I assumed you had one record for each cell.  If that's wrong, then how is the file related to the cells?

Comment: You are right with there being one record for each cell. I see what you're saying. Essentially what I'm getting from you is that 'each' Cell itself is looping through that for loop, and displaying that specific last record only because it's the last record in that specific cell. So of course it's going to show the last record. So I do understand my mistake now. 

Which leads me to the next question. When I set the cell's textLabel, you were saying set it with the ObjectAtIndex. Correct? If so, how would I set the textLabel at the specific ObjectAtIndex?

Comment: I'm suggesting `indexPath.row` should match the array offset.  (Also, is there a reason you're setting cell data here instead of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?)

Comment: I actually had just changed the method to perform this for loop within the cellForRowAtIndexPath. Good call though. 

As for the indexPath.row...again, another good call. Today is my Monday with being off and away from code for a bit. 

I appreciate your help, copy and paste your last comment as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Sue those half knowledge tutorials which suggest `valueForKey` for obviously non-KVC usage, sigh.

Comment: I believe in some cases KVC is the right approach, though not in every case. If you can shed some light on what you would've done so developers like myself who are a little newer can learn the proper ways; that would be nice. But I'm aware that KVC is not always necessary and the right approach, but there are instances where it's best and necessary.

Comment: For example a simple rule : Retrieving single values from dictionaries in table data source arrays and `NSUserDefaults` use **always** `objectForKey:`, in case of the data source array even use key subscripting `dict["key"]`.

Comment: Gotcha, understood. Now just to satisfy my curiosity, what are the advantages of using objectForKey over valueForKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove for loop from Your code.
because it will always assign last value in your datasourceArray
and use

```
[tableDataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

instead of

```
[tableDataSourceArray objectAtIndex:objectToDisplay]
```

Comment: Here's my next question for you. When you say remove the for loop, the base reason behind my for loop is basically to iterate through each record, and check for a value "failed" for specific Keys. So if there is a failed value for two specific keys, the TableView should be populated with those specific objects...which would be a NSMutableDictonary containing those corresponding key's and values.